# Empty usage reports?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

since the past 7-10 days, I'm getting back empty usage reports from the googleapis.com endpoint. (e.g., https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/users/all/dates/2019-02-23 )

Any known issues going on? This same endpoint was working just fine (say, till 22nd Feb).. And my access token works fine for a different API (e.g., https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer)

Thanks

Comment: Were you suppose to use `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/users/all/dates/yyyy-mm-dd date
?parameters=application` to [get all user activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users#get_all_user_usage) and `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/users/userKey/dates/yyyy-mm-dd date
?parameters=application` for a [specific customer account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-usage-users#get_user_usage)?